# JAVA apps and ECLIPSE can't connect to internet

Tags: java, eclipse, url, connection, jsoup

Ok so I wrote a piece of code testing ability of my java to connect to internet. It is supposed to fetch html from www.google.com and display the contents in a JFrame's JTextArea object.
Here's the code, so you can have clear picture:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JSoupFetchTest extends JFrame{
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0";
    boolean jsoupcond = true;
    String address = "http://www.google.com";
    JTextArea text;
    public JSoupFetchTest(){
        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        text.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        text.setVisible(true);
        text.setLineWrap(true);     
        this.add(text);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();        
        gogo();
    }

    private void gogo() {
        if(jsoupcond){
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\nstart...");

            try {
                text.setText(text.getText() +"\nConnecting to " +address+ "...");   
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(address).userAgent(userAgent).get();
                text.setText(text.getText() +"\nConverting page document into text");
                String s = doc.toString();
                text.setText(text.getText() +"\nText: \n" +s);
                System.out.println();
            } catch (Exception e) {            
                text.setText(text.getText() +"\n" +e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\nEnd.");
        }
        String html = downloadHtml(address);
        text.setText(text.getText() +"\nDownloading HTML...");
        text.setText(text.getText() +"\nHTML:");
        text.setText(text.getText() +"\n" +html);
    }

    private String downloadHtml(String path) {
        text.setText(text.getText() +"\ndownloadHtml entry point...");
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\ntry block entered...");
            String result = "";
            String line;

            URL url = new URL(path);
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\nabout to open url stream...");
            is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\nurl stream opened...");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\nstarting to read lines...");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            text.setText(text.getText() +"\nreading lines finished...");
            return result;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) { }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JSoupFetchTest();       
    }
}
```

I should also add that:
1. My eclipse (cause that's what I'm using) can't connect to marketplace nor can't fetch updates.
2. Eclipse's web browser works fine.
3. My system's browser (Mozilla Firefox) connects fine
4. I exported JSoupFetchTest into a runnable jar and tried to run it from system's level, with no effect
5. I am running Windows 7 Professional MSDN version
6. I contacted eclipse support and they concluded it is not eclipse's fault and suggested that I'm behind a proxy.
7. I contacted my ISP to see if I indeed am and they said I am not.
8. I changed my JAVA's network settings so now it connects "directly". Before the setting was "use browser settings" and it didn't work either.
9. My eclipse's Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections active provider is set to "Native", I also tried "Direct"
10. Method downloadHtml(String path) stops at "is = url.openStream();" and goes on forever...

The exception I get from JSoup is:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:703)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1534)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:453)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
    at JSoupFetchTest.gogo(JSoupFetchTest.java:42)
    at JSoupFetchTest.<init>(JSoupFetchTest.java:32)
    at JSoupFetchTest.main(JSoupFetchTest.java:92)
```

I also tried to set JSoup.connect's timeout to infinity. Then it goes on forever.

Before you guys say that my question is a duplicate, or delegate me to other, external possible solutions to my problem, believe me - either the question is mine or I was there - I browse internet in search for solution for weeks now and I feel like pulling my hair out...
Please help if you can cause it prevents me from installing stuff in my eclipse and from developing anything else than stand alone apps...

Comment: And what exactly is the unexpected behavior you are observing? Is there an exception; timeout, hang?! "Can't connect to the internet" is a bit very unspecific.

Comment: @Jägermeister Sorry I missed that. See the edited question.

Comment: Good, one step further. What I forgot to ask: what happens when you take eclipse out of the equation; meaning: can you run the program successfully from command line?

Comment: @Jägermeister That's why I delegate the output to JTextArea instead of Console. I exported the program to runnableJAR and when I run it from window's level, it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Do you have to use JSoup?  Can you test with just a regular socket?  It looks like a local configuration problem, taking JSoup out of the picture would eliminate some chance of configuration problems with that library.

Comment: If eclipse doesn't matter; why do you waste your (and probably our) time by leaving it in the equation? And I agree with markspace - start with the "simplest" example possible; when that works - then think about making your example more complex.

Comment: You probably have a firewall preventing Java to connect. Disable it.

Comment: @markspac method downloadHTML(String address) is not using JSoup and it goes on forever...

Comment: @Jägermeister They said it doesn't matter. Maybe it doesn't, but I included it to give you guys a full picture of the situation. Besides, in my opinion eclipse's behavior is related to the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet Firewall on what level? Could you be more specific? Windows firewall? My ISP has a firewall, I switched it off and it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about a firewall on your own system.

Comment: @JBNizet No change... I also added eclipse to list of programs that are allowed to communicate through firewall with no effect.

Comment: I have jdk1.8.0_25, jdk1.8.0_40, jre1.8.0_40 and jre7 installed on my system. Is it possible that multiple installations are the problem? Maybe I should uninstall all of it and install java from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You need a socket number after the URL -- "http:/www.google.com:80" works.  JSoup likely uses defaults for that, but opening the URL as a stream in Java does not.

Comment: I added port number as you suggested but it still behaves the same way. I'll try to switch off the firewall as JBNizet suggested and see if that helps.

Comment: You're right -- I took off the port number (and commented out all the JSoup stuff) and it still worked.  So adding the port number is not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following program works for me.  So Java and `JSoup` are working.  It has to be some sort of local configuration problem with your network.  Check your firewall, routers, gateway, and Java permissions.  Do a clean rebuild of your project.  Etc.  Comment out lines until it does work and then put the lines back one at a time until you find the problem.  Etc.

```
package stuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class SocketTest
{

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
   {
      URL url = new URL( "http://www.google.com" );
      URLConnection sock = url.openConnection();
      InputStream ins = sock.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ins, "UTF-8" ) );
      for( String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
         System.out.println( line );
      }
      ins.close();

      Document doc = Jsoup.connect( "http://www.google.com" ).get();
      System.out.println( doc.toString() );

      String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0";
      Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect( "http://www.google.com" ).userAgent(userAgent).get();
      System.out.println( doc2.toString() );

   }
}
```

Comment: Firewall switched off... windows one and ISP one too, I know my gateway address but I have no idea what to do with it, I honestly don't know what to look for in router settings (and since browser works fine I can't see how is it useful. Could you explain please?). Java permissions are set to lowest possible which is "high", however java updates fine, just java apps do not.